# Equivalent of a "weight" parameter in pyGTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

When making a GUI in pyGTK, I frequently want to have multiple child objects expanding with a specified ratio. As an example (not my particular application, just something I felt was easy to draw), imagine I were creating some sort of photo viewer that displays EXIF metadata in a tab on the right, and I'd like these to maintain a 2:1 ratio, so the photo always takes up 2/3rds of the width and the metadata takes up 1/3rd of the width:

[image]

In wxWindows, you would assign each of these items a "weight" parameter, so the left `VBox` would have `weight = 2` and the right `VBox` would have `weight = 1`, then as you resized the window, the containers would maintain their 2:1 ratio. In GTK+, however, it seems like all you can do is choose whether you want the containers to expand or not, so in this case I'd use something like:

```
top_level_hbox.pack_start(exif_container, expand=False)
top_level_hbox.pack_start(photo_container, expand=True, fill=True)
```

I believe, however, that this would leave `exif_container` with a fixed size based on the size of its child widgets, and `photo_container` would grow as necessary, so even if they originally had a 2:1 ratio, this would not survive the window being resized. Is there a simple or at least standard way of doing this sort of "weighted expansion" in GTK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a table layout.  Ie. rather than use a hbox, create a gtk.Table, with a single row and 3 columns.  Attach the photo part to span the first two columns, and the status panel to the third, which should maintain the 2:1 ratio you want as you expand them.

Eg.

```
table = gtk.Table(rows=1, columns=3)
table.attach(photo_container, 0, 2, 0, 1) # Span column 0..2
table.attach(exif_container, 2, 3, 0, 1)  # Span final column
window.add(table)
```

Comment: The question seems to be for GTK+ 2 but I'll add this for completeness: GtkTable has been deprecated since GTK+ 3.4. GtkGrid offers the same features -- including homogeneous columns/rows.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Brian's suggestion to use a gtk.Table. To force the table cells to all be the same size you can specify `homogeneous=True` in the constructor.

Another approach is to pack photo_container and exif_container into a gtk.VPaned container, which allows the user to control the space used by the two child containers, and you can also control it dynamically using the `set_position()` method, although that can get a bit fiddly.

Personally, I'd be inclined to just use a simple gtk.HBox with a fixed size exif_container for this interface, although I'd probably put photo_container into a gtk.ScrolledWindow.

Comment: Good suggestions, though, like I said, I'm not actually making a photo viewer, it was just something that I thought I could draw easily where you'd want to keep a fixed ratio that's not 1:1.